# Minimum and Maximum of an Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

$y = 10P_1 + 2P_2$ where $P_1 + P_2 = 1$

Why is the value of "$y$" between $2$ and $10$ (inclusive)?

Edit: oops, you're right, both $P$ are >= 0.

Comment: From what is given, this is not true. For example, if $P_1=-1,P_2=2$ then $y$ takes  the value $-6$. However, if we assume that $P_1,P_2$ are non-negative, then  this is true : substitute $P_1 = 1-P_2$ in the first equation, and note that $y$ then decreases with $P_2$. Now, knowing the maximum and minimum possible values of $P_2$ gives the conclusion(If $P_2,P_1$ were not assumed positive, no such value would exist, so $y$ could take values outside the given range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P_1+P_2=1$ we have $P_2=1-P_1$ thus $y=10P_1+2P_2=10P_1+2(1-P_1)=8P_1+2$.

Now we have a function with one variable: $y=8P_1+2$, this function is always increasing, so $\max(P_1)\implies\max(y)$, so what you suggest is false, we can see that with an example:

$$P_1=10\implies P_2=-9,P_1+P_2=10-9=1\\10P_1+2P_2= 100-18=80+2=82>10$$

---

## But

If it is given that both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are positive then $\max(P_1)=1\implies P_2=0\implies \max(y)=10$ and $\min(P_1)=0\implies P_2=1\implies \min(y)=2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;y = 10P_1 + 2P_2 = 8 P_1+2(P_1+P_2)=8P_1+2\,$. Assuming *positive* $P_{1,2}$ (which the question did not explicitly state) $\,0 \le P_1 \le 1 \implies 0 \le 8P_1 \le8 \implies \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value is 10 (with $P_1=1$ and $P_2=0$), the minimum value is 2 (with $P_1=0$ and $P_2=1$). You just connect these two numbers through a line segment.